# Python Get Body from Azure EventData Generator object

Tags: python, compression, azure-eventhub

When using the python `EventHubConsumerClient` to read data from an Azure EventHub. The `receive` (and `receive_batch`) function return an `EventData` object. Normally you could just use the `body_as_json()` or `body_as_str()` function to return the body of the object.
But if you body is compressed these methods will return an exception.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the byte array of the event body is to turn the `body` property of the EventData object into a list and access the first element, like this.

```
bytearray = list(msg.body)[0]
zlib.decompress(bytearray)
```

I know this is very hacky, but I have not found any other way to receive the raw body. I hope this help somebody out there and if you know of a better way, feel free to share!